# GAS WEB-приложение не возвращает ответ на POST-запрос

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-apps-script, cors

Из расширения для Хрома обращаюсь на JS к скрипту на GAS развернутому как веб-приложение. Скрипт запроса на JS:

```
const fetchData = async (scriptURL, data) => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(scriptURL, {
                mode: 'no-cors',
                method: 'POST',
                referrer: "",
                redirect: 'follow',
                body: JSON.stringify(data), // данные м
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
                        
            });                             
            if (response != "") var json = await response.json();
            console.log('Успех:', JSON.stringify(json));
        } 
        catch (e){console.log('Ошибка:', e.message)}
            console.log('Tect:');
            
        return
    }
```

Запрос проходит скрипт GAS его обрабатывает корректно и назад возвращает JSON вот так:

```
function doPost(e) { 
    // обработка
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(response)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

Однако назад расширение Хрома не получает тело ответа, выдавая во вкладке DevTools=>Network=>Response ошибку "Failed to load response data".
Ниже приведен первоначальный запрос и ответ:

```
    Request URL: https://script.google.com/macros/s/fycbzwUUktSYViIkE-kEc9-C73ztt6Mm14GTW9tEFezIdt/exec
    Request Method: POST
    Status Code: 302 
    Remote Address: 209.85.233.101:443
    Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
    access-control-allow-origin: *
    alt-svc: h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-25=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000
    cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
    content-encoding: gzip
    content-length: 414
    content-security-policy: script-src 'report-sample' 'nonce-OewkPQPEKTjPXx3gSzqVwg' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'strict-dynamic' https: http:;object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';report-uri /cspreport
    content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    date: Sun, 05 Jul 2020 21:47:26 GMT
    expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
    location: https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=bRiwWyQk_oa-B99FJ5_g00zqWPRqvIGFcwdKje92QVPMyyktfI_a_dUeDarNaYb-5NdZdY8r5obHevJSniGht8HDZNzK9Gm5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_1xSncGQajx_ryfhECjZEnOhtPz9z4I3dzdyyINU3UA0pwpiENh8R4k1UDc5fBUkkDEzr0xNxtlsP-6Y5oFxMMg&lib=MpU1M31wDqWrblgsshTKAbKcDiPyCPu1i
    pragma: no-cache
    server: GSE
    set-cookie: SIDCC=Ai4QfEY-gvacLHt4o10ILj73SwnH7BM-HG6BYn8X7VZLgyA5FqZ9LxvN1lrJi7lc6SNYpwxa1EC; expires=Mon, 05-Jul-2021 21:47:26 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; priority=high
    status: 302
    x-content-type-options: nosniff
    x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
    x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
**Request Headers**
    :authority: script.google.com
    :method: POST
    :path: /macros/s/fycbzwUUktSYViIkE-kEc9-C73ztt6Mm14GTW9tEFezIdt/exec
    :scheme: https
    accept: */*
    accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    accept-language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
    content-length: 99
    content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
    cookie: .....
    origin: chrome-extension://gabejmdkdkojddbfifhcceicplhpdkmn
    sec-fetch-dest: empty
    sec-fetch-mode: no-cors
    sec-fetch-site: none
    user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36
    x-client-data: CIe2yQEIorbJAQjBtskBCKmdygEI/rzKAQjAvcoBCOfIygEYm77KAQ==
```

В чем может быть проблема? Бьюсь  2 недели, не могу найти нигде. Такое ощущение что проблема связана с CORS и 302 редиректом (google посылает ответ с другого урла).
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: UID пути конечной точки должен начинаться с `AK...` или `AJ...`. У вас префикса нет `ros/s/[AK..._]fycbzwUUktS`. Может быть ошибка просто в опечатке?

Comment: contributorpw, я просто его подтер, когда сюда выкладывал, также как и куки.

Comment: В любом случае, пока не видится ничего особенного, кроме того что вы возвращаете JSON, чего обычно не надо делать, т.к. скрипты автоматизируют поставку контента в зависимости от заголовков. Управлять cors без сервера так же бессмысленно. Для отладки нужен действительный адрес.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось непросто:

1. WEB-приложение гугла не поддерживает метод OPTIONS соотвtтсвенно оно не может ответить на предварительный запрос, который будет с телом JSON. [См.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62587453/xmlhttprequest-blocked-by-cors-policy-when-posting-data-to-a-web-app)
2. Я не понимаю, как это работает, но это работает,я проверил. Автор тоже объяснить не может. [См.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62763290/web-app-does-respods-with-a-302-status-on-a-post-request/62765610#62765610)